# Notify the OP when a question is about to be removed by Roomba

Tags: feature-request, questions, notifications, auto-delete

Would it be possible to notify the OP when one of his/her questions is about to be removed by [Roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78048/178179)? I don't think it's very respectful to the OP to delete content without any warning and possibility to recover the question.

For example, at some point just on one Stack Exchange site, 10 of my questions were going to be erased in one month, none of them got downvoted, just no upvote and 1 year of low activity, which is commonplace for that site. It's hard to keep track of all endangered questions on all the Stack Exchange sites I am part of.

Related feature request: [Decrease the required view count to prevent Roomba deletion when score = 0 on smaller sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355097)

Comment: I would take a slightly different approach: don't mention it's going to be deleted, just send notification like "We noticed this question might get more attention if you will edit and improve it" - notifications should always be positive, that's why we don't have any when posts we wrote are closed or deleted.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Sure, that's a good example of notification. I'm not sure that notifications should always be positive, but anyway that's another debate. I just want some kind of notifications.