# How can I view the median number of views on questions in a given SE website?

Tags: support, questions, data-explorer, statistics, views

Ideally, I also would like to see the standard deviation, average and interquartile range (IQR), add have some way to plot question age vs. median number of views on the questions with IQR or standard deviation as error bar (or have a box plot per age bucket).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

T-SQL (and hence SEDE) doesn't have a `MEDIAN` function, but it does have [`PERCENTILE_CONT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percentile-cont-transact-sql). [This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1337344/view-count-statistics) may help: the median number of views on Meta Stack Exchange is 114, the IQR is 67 to 216 and the standard deviation is a whopping 4772. Apparently, there are many outliers...

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1337464/view-count-statistics-by-age-group) is one which groups questions by age:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The high standard deviation partly results from considering questions of very different age (from age=0 day to age~=12.3 years). I think grouping by age bucket would help, maybe via https://am2.co/2019/10/how-to-create-date-buckets-in-t-sql/ but not that straightforward.

Comment: See Yaakov's question on SO: "[Function to Calculate Median in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1342898/3648282)". Some of the answers claim a few hundred times faster than PERCENTILE_CONT, which is important for time-outs on SO queries. --- Disclaimer: Not that I understand the question or answer, , if this isn't helpful Glorfindel I'm happy to delete this comment. --- Despite the title, the question is clearly about "Transact-SQL".

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I've updated the post with a query which groups questions by age in years.

Comment: @Rob yeah, it's probably not the most performant way, but it's easier to write :) And [it even works on the largest database in the network](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1337464/view-count-statistics-by-age-group) so I'm not going to optimize it.

Comment: OK (not using median function). The StDev [*crushes* the other values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0w6YI.jpg), so it might be more useful as a SQRT(SD); to retain resolution.