# Add an option to sort the Recently Deleted Questions by deletion date

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, sorting, deleted-posts-pages

Feature request: Add an option to sort the Recently Deleted Questions by deletion date. That'd be useful when the page contains several questions, e.g.

[image: Screenshot of the Recently Deleted Questions page of the OP, containing a large amount of questions.]

Example of Recently Deleted Questions page:

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions

Currently the questions are sorted by modification date.

Comment: Have you tried `is:question deleted:yes user:me` in the search box? Then click "Newest"

Comment: @DavidPostill only works if enough rep (10k on graduated websites)

Comment: Well you need 10K to see deleted questions ... unless they are your own ...

Comment: @DavidPostill `Recently Deleted Questions` is only to view one's own questions.

Comment: Pro-tip: try to have less deleted questions, then there is no need to sort them ;)

Comment: @Luuklag yes [Decrease the required view count to prevent Roomba deletion when score = 0 on smaller sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355097/178179). Try asking some questions on SE websites with low frequentation per question and with low vote activity  :( also I've asked 30 times more questions than you, so that doesn't help reduce the size of my `Recently Deleted Questions` list.