# How can Stack Exchange encourage more voting?

Tags: discussion, voting

The following search link queries Stack Overflow for Q&A with an accepted answer, and the question score is zero. Add a [tag] for results relevant to you.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=hasaccepted%3a1%20score%3a0

This search returns millions of questions that were good enough to answer, and the asker took the time to accept an answer. Yet the question is left with zero votes.

At this time, the majority of the questions in the first 50 search results are by users with 0-100 reputation.

Giving these new users positive reinforcement goes a long way to engagement and keeping the community alive.

How can Stack Exchange encourage more voting?

Comment: There's an interesting [set of proposals from 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80312/why-are-votes-per-post-on-the-decrease-what-can-we-do-to-improve-this). Hasn't received traction yet. There's a civic duty badge however.

Comment: "This search returns millions of Questions that were good enough to answer" I don't see the connection between "post an answer" and "upvote the question".

Comment: Also, I notice that when you say "voting" you seem to mean "upvoting". Downvoting is also crucial part of the way Stack sites work. And even more often neglected, as evidenced by the fact you didn't even bring it up.

Comment: @VLAZ If a question doesn't deserve an upvote perhaps it doesn't deserve an answer either.

Comment: @PM2Ring I see many questions every day that deserve neither and still get them. Bajillion-dupes of *very* simple problems may get 5 answers in 3 minutes. Using `<=` instead of `<` in a for loop, for example. I do not believe that such a question deserves 5 answers. Much less 5 upvotes, as you and OP seem to suggest.

Comment: @VLAZ No, that's not what I meant. Such questions deserve neither answers nor upvotes.

Comment: @PM2Ring in that case, we agree - there isn't a strong connection between posting an answer and upvoting a question.

Comment: I certainly did *not* intend to imply that a question must be worthy of upvotes merely because it's received answers. On the contrary, people should *only* be answering questions if they think the question is good. Otherwise, they should be downvoting, close-voting, or if the question is salvageable, helping the OP to turn it into a good question.

Comment: That's one more reason to [decrease the required view count to prevent Roomba deletion when score = 0, at the very least on smaller sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355097/178179).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's be precise as of [last Sunday](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1628470?opt.textResults=true):

| total | closed | upmod | downmod | no vote |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4,563,242 | 154,418 | 557,617 | 557,569 | 4,086,856 |

So that is the number of questions, overall, that have zero score and an accepted answer, but now also showing closed and voted on questions.

Most new questions are asked by users new to the site, so your argument why we need more voting

> At this time, the majority of the Questions in the first 50 search results are by users with 0-100 reputation.

is caused by sorting on newest, not due to statistical relevance.

I don't think voters care at all how much reputation a user has, and rightfully so. Not being a statistics person myself, let me dare a graph to show that reputation is not a metric that will [predict votes](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1628473#graph):

[image: Graph showing number of users (y-axis) that have 0-scored questions and their reputation (x-axis), reputation 0 shows around 300,000 users, reputation 100 shows around 600,000 users and then dropping to 400,000 and 100,000]

Given the close to 600,000 users with somewhere around 100 reputation I count as evidence. Those users probably earned the association bonus. So they managed to post reasonable content on another site in the network. That still didn't help them to ask a question deemed valuable by the Stack Overflow voters.

Isn't there a voting problem then? Yes, there is:

[image: Up, down and total votes, downvotes way at the bottom, upvotes high, trend downwards]

In the graph you clearly see the effect of the previous attempt by Stack Exchange to guide voters. The welcoming wagon had its effect, fewer users cast downvotes. Something we won't recover from in the next [6 to 8](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) years.

The overall trend is that fewer votes are being cast. For Stack Overflow this isn't that remarkable. Given we have existed for a long time, most common questions that users fresh to programming ask are already answered. Those questions get close voted instead of upvoted. There simply aren't that many new questions that are a valuable addition to the body of knowledge Stack Overflow wants and needs to be. Unfortunately the few good questions often get swamped by the sheer overload of duplicates, poorly researched and other not answerable space and time-wasters. Those few good questions then don't get the attention they need and so they go vote-less.

So, let's encourage voting then. Specially of the downvote kind. Casting six downvotes in three years isn't that helpful. Quality control starts by preventing not valuable content to linger. Let's explain on Meta, in Chat, on [the blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/), on [the podcast](https://stackoverflow.blog/podcast/) and on Twitter that our unique features to vote on content makes for an incredible collection of knowledge that is actively maintained. Being part of a community that contributes to that goal should be intrinsic motivation to keep up with it, vote, edit, and flag. We need a Celebrate Curators Wagon. I certainly can use that.